# Set datatables to be equivalent

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

This is probably a simple question but I am not experienced in C#.

I have 2 datatables, 1 is basically a copy of the other (like a table to review information). To set the values this is what I am doing now:

```
    string attribute1 = "";
    string attribute2 = "";
    string attribute3 = ""; 
    .....
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=user_id;password=pwd;server=serverstring;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=database;connection timeout=30"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE parameter=@identifying_parameter", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identifying_parameter", "example");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                attribute1 = Convert.ToString(reader["attribute1"]);
                attribute2 = Convert.ToString(reader["attribute2"]);
                attribute3 = Convert.ToString(reader["attribute3"]);
                .....
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=user_2;password=pwd;server=serverstring;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=database;connection timeout=30"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, ...)  VALUES(@attribute1, @attribute2, @attribute3, ...)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attribute1", attribute1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attribute2", attribute2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@attribute3", attribute3);
            ....
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(result);
            con.Close();
            da.Dispose();
        }
     }
```

Obviously I might have a lot of attributes, so is there a simpler way to set every attribute in the table to be equal in C#?

Comment: If the two tables are in the same database and have the same schema, you could just execute the query `INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE parameter=@identifying_parameter`.

Comment: you can't do better than turning it to a one liner and you should create your own Extension method , you moistly need to use reflection

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT..INTO..SELECT

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("user id=user_2;password=pwd;server=serverstring;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=database;connection timeout=30"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO table2 (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3, ...)  
        SELECT attribute1, attribute2, attribute3 ... FROM table1
        WHERE parameter=@identifying_parameter                  
        ", con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@identifying_parameter", "example");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(result);
        con.Close();
        da.Dispose();
    }
}
```

You can use * instead of specifying the column name, although which is not good practice..

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a second Table identical (or "equivalent" as per your definition) to the first one (for certainty let's call it sourceTable), you can use `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` Method (DataTable)(re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
using (SqlConnection YourConnection= new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
{
       YourConnection.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(YourConnection))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.YourDestinationTable";

            try
            {
                // Write from the source to the destination.
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceTable);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
}
```

In order to get a sourceTable you can use the following code snippet:

```
DataTable sourceTable = SqlReadDB(YourConnString, "SELECT *")

private static DataTable SqlReadDB(string ConnString, string SQL)
{
    DataTable _dt;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection _connSql = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand _commandl = new SqlCommand(SQL, _connSql))
            {
                _commandSql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _connSql.Open();
                using (SqlCeDataReader _dataReaderSql = _commandSql.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    _dt = new DataTable();
                    _dt.Load(_dataReaderSqlCe);
                    _dataReaderSql.Close();
                }
            }
            _connSqlCe.Close();
            return _dt;
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

}

Hope this may help.